# Ubuntu 12.04LTS becoms slow and jerky randomly for a mintue and then becomes normal by itself

Tags: 12.04, mouse

I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS on my Toshiba satellite L510 and I have only Ubuntu installed.
The system becomes slow and jerky by itself after every 10minutes or so and the remains like that for less than a minute. Then becomes normal by itself.

When the systems becomes slow; mouse movement becomes jerky, on right click the menu loads super slow, the windows minimize very slowly. The major problem is the mouse becoming jerky.

Can someone please suggest anything which can solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you determine what system resource is limiting performance during slow down. By that I mean is your CPU at 100% or maybe your hard drive is running like mad. There are system monitor tools that will give you this information in real time such as "gnome-system-monitor".

The system monitor can also tell you what process is using the resource. You could also use a terminal program like "top" or the nicer looking "htop" to identify the process.

Comment: Hi Sean, I have been observing the system monitor for quite some time now. The graph of RAM is perfectly stable and is at 50% usage. The graph for CPUs move around and below 50% too. My hard disks are almost empty. Most of the time I run only firefox, rhythmbox and one IDE only. Firefox takes around 400mb of RAM on an average. Still my system randomly becomes slow and the mouse becomes very jerky. Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: Zaphod when I referred to your hard drive running I meant I/O activity to your disk. You would notice the hard drive light being solidly on during this period. Potentially the system is writing the contents of RAM to Swap file system frequently, gnome-system-monitor would record this in the resources tab. If the slow down is every ten minutes exactly your system maybe running an activity every ten minutes. Check if cron is running something at time interval by looking at the time stamps of cron in the syslog: **bold**less /var/log/syslog | grep -i cron